# using templates with multiple object types

Tags: c++

I need to write a container template class `<T, R>` where T is an object and R can be either `vector<T*>` or `list<T*>`. i need to support common operations like insert(T) size() etc...

I am holding a class member called `T data` to be the list or the vector. the problem is, how do i write the code so at runtime i know which operation to invoke from `std::list` or `std::vector` ?

for example, to get the fist element in the container i would have to invoke `data[0]` in the vector case and `data.front()` in lists case. should i just use `typeid` operator ?

```
if (typeid(R) ==  typeid(vector<T*>))
  then ...
else if (typeid(R) == typeid(list<T*>))
 then ...
```

Or is there a better way ?

Comment: Any time you write `if` tree with `typeid` in it, you're doing it wrong. In this case, both list and vector share much of the interface, including `front()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use iterators -- they are standard idioms in the STL.  Use `begin()` to get the iterator pointing to the beginning of the collection and `end()` to get the end (more precisely, the iterator pointing to the element "after" the last in the collection).  You can also use `push_back()` with both `list<>` and `vector<>` to add elements to the end of the collection, `insert()` to add an element to a specific position and `erase` to delete an element from the collection.  Check out the reference ([vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/), [list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/)) for more common functions.

The idea is that method calls in templates are not checked until the point of instantiation (and sepcifically until the call of template functions), so the above mentioned calls will bind to the exact collection type you specified in the template

Comment: That won't prevent the use of some other container that also supports iterators and `push_back()`.

Comment: I'ts not so much that i want to prevent other containers as much as i want to duplicate code as little as possible. still not sure what would be the better approach out of what mentioned here and what @mfontanini wrote

Comment: @Michael - I think Let_Me_Be meant that you can use this approach with other collections as well (not just vector and list), which is a good thing.  I did not emphasize this iun my answer as you were looking specifically for vector and list

Comment: @Michael - My suggestion will work "out of the box" with most all STL containers (that support the operations you wish to use), while you will need to write more code for specialization of each case if you go with mfontanini's approach

Answer (score 4):

You should use template specialization. You can read a good article about it [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/template_specialization.html).

Answer (score 0):

If the set is so limited you can do something like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

template < typename T, typename V >
class X;

class XImpl {};

template < typename T >
class X< T, vector<T*> > : XImpl {};


template < typename T >
class X< T, list<T*> > : XImpl {};

int main()
{
    X< int,vector<int*> > a;
    X< double, list<double*> > b;
    X<int, int> c; // error
}
```

And put your implementation into `XImpl`.

Edit: XImpl will most likely be templated as well. This code is just demonstrating the guard against any other container than vector, or list. And of course a guard against bad combinations like `X<int, vector<double*> >`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the one mfontanini gave, use specialization.
For your specific example though, vector supports front too, and vector and list have the same functions as much as it possible